# How do you blur faces in YouTube studio circa 2018?

Tags: youtube

I can't see any option to blur faces. I'm sure I saw the option in the past. I don't know if YouTube has removed the option, or just moved it, like in some around September 2018.

I don't see the option here:

[image]

or here:

[image]

or here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [the blog post re-launching the feature](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2017/08/blur-select-faces-with-updated-blur.html) last year

> To get to Blur Faces, go to the Enhance tool for a video you own. This can be done from the Video Manager or watch page. The Blur Faces tool can be found under the “Blurring Effects” tab of Enhancements. The following image shows how to get there.
>
> [image: navigating to blur faces]

There you can select the faces you wish to blur. The support article for the tool is [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9057652?hl=en&ref_topic=3014750), but it skips over where you find it.